Weird rectangular bump when Bridging edge loops
I am modeling a mug and I want to connect the handle to the Mug seamlessly like a real mug.

But when I connect the models together via Bridge Edge Loop, There's this weird rectangular bump that ruins the connections and I have no way of fixing it.


I tried fixing it by shrinking some of the edges and faces, moving the handle closer, and widening the handle to fit the faces on the mug but the bump is still there. Does anyone know how to fix this?
